# xcode error when using old library

Tags: ios, xcode

I update my Mac to 1.9.4 and install Xcode 6, I created a new project and copy `UIBubbleTable` source from the project which I used this library before and still work fine according to my last time check.

The old project works fine with this library, but new project gets error.

[image]

I've added every requires framework but still error.

Here are my error logs, please help.

```
CompileC /Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NSBubbleData.o Troll\ Kitty/NSBubbleData.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty"
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -iquote /Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/Troll\ Kitty-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/Troll\ Kitty-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/Troll\ Kitty-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/Troll\ Kitty-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NSBubbleData.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NSBubbleData.dia -c /Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll\ Kitty/Troll\ Kitty/Troll\ Kitty/NSBubbleData.m -o /Users/vietnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Troll_Kitty-gggxclyccrfjrdfavpkgnqibgoth/Build/Intermediates/Troll\ Kitty.build/Debug-iphoneos/Troll\ Kitty.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NSBubbleData.o

In file included from /Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.m:11:
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:23:41: error: unknown type name 'UIView'
@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
                                        ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:23:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:24:33: error: unknown type name 'UIEdgeInsets'
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets insets;
                                ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:25:31: error: unknown type name 'UIImage'
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *avatar;
                              ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:25:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *avatar;
^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:27:31: error: unknown type name 'UIImageView'
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *viewAvatar;
                              ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:27:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *viewAvatar;
^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:31:22: error: expected a type
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type;
                     ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:32:22: error: expected a type
+ (id)dataWithImage:(UIImage *)image date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type;
                     ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:33:21: error: expected a type
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets;
                    ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:33:87: error: expected a type
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets;
                                                                                      ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:34:21: error: expected a type
+ (id)dataWithView:(UIView *)view date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets;
                    ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.h:34:87: error: expected a type
+ (id)dataWithView:(UIView *)view date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets;
                                                                                      ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.m:46:7: error: unknown type name 'UIEdgeInsets'
const UIEdgeInsets textInsetsMine = {5, 10, 11, 17};
      ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.m:47:7: error: unknown type name 'UIEdgeInsets'
const UIEdgeInsets textInsetsSomeone = {5, 15, 11, 10};
      ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.m:102:7: error: unknown type name 'UIEdgeInsets'
const UIEdgeInsets imageInsetsMine = {11, 13, 16, 22};
      ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.m:103:7: error: unknown type name 'UIEdgeInsets'
const UIEdgeInsets imageInsetsSomeone = {11, 18, 16, 14};
      ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.m:105:22: error: expected a type
+ (id)dataWithImage:(UIImage *)image date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type
                     ^
/Users/vietnguyen/Desktop/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/Troll Kitty/NSBubbleData.m:114:22: error: expected a type
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type
                     ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like that library expects a .pch file which imports UIKit/UIKit.h (see UIBubbleTableViewExample-Prefix.pch in the example directory). You can either add a similar pch file to your project. Or you can add the following to the header files where you are seeing those errors:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help, in xcode 5 it will create this file automatic, why xcode 6 don't do that?

Comment: i added UIKit to the class file throwing the error and still getting the error.